# Overlay text over an image and align ALL center using only css and/or HTML

Tags: html, css, image, centering

I've read through several posts regarding both overlaying text over an image, AND on centering. None of the answers work for my situation. Below is both the HTML and the CSS I'm using. Frankly - the only thing I've found that will work to center my image UNDER my text is to revert to using  tags! I'm frustrated to say the least.

It "should" be really simple, but it's not!

```css
#header
{
    height: 140px;
    position: relative;
     /*background: url('http://i105.photobucket.com/albums/m229/ayliea/ColeensDA_Avatar_zps7d63fb7c.jpg');
   background-color: #E7D4DE; for testing background colors*/
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center top;
    font-family: Segoe Script, Lucida handwriting, brush script mt, 
    monotype cosira, Apple Chancery, comic Sans MS Italic;
    top: 10px;
}
}
#header p
{font-size: 1.25em; font-weight: normal;}
#header .imgcenter
{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    
    z-index:100;
}
.topcenter
{
    position: absolute;
    top: -20px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #0200a1;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    text-decoration: none;
} 
.topmiddle
{
    position: absolute;
    top:3.5em;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 4px;
    color: #c0c0c0;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height:1.1em;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
         <img class="imgcenter" src="http://i105.photobucket.com/albums/m229/ayliea/ColeensDA_Avatar_zps7d63fb7c.jpg" alt="Aylissa"  />
     <div class="topcenter">
     <p><a href="default.aspx">Testing My text overlay with<br />trademark symbol and link<sup>&#174;</sup></a></p>
     </div>
     <p class="topmiddle">Second line of text that<br />
     needs centered on top of image</p> </div>
```

But unless I use the old-fashioned  tag, I just can't seem to get the darn image to both center AND either show (sometimes it disappears!) or have the text overlay it correctly!

Can anyone help me with this issue?

P.S. I used the suggestions from here: http://www.the-art-of-web.com/css/textoverimage/ to do the overlay.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are just missing to add `text-align: center;` to your `#header`

and, as a note, `background-repeat: no-repeat;` and  `background-position: center top;` are useless properties in your css as it would just affect any image you add as `background-image`. It won't do anything with a html `img`

Second note: you can also get rid of `margin-left: auto;`, `margin-right: auto;` and `z-index:100;` in your `.imgcenter` for a cleaner css sheet (`z-index` won't ever work on any element unless you add a position NOT stactic in that element, `position:static` is the position of every single html element by default.)

Comment: Thanks for the response, I appreciate it. This is weird. I first added just the text-align:center; (which I really have tried before, but not with the in-line block for the .img)  and then I removed the extra code from the .imgcenter .css. It worked. Then, I removed the extra background .css (I just forget to rem those out when I moved the image to the HTML) and it stopped working! Argh! So I closed the browser, and re-ran the HTML. At first it didn't work, but then I refreshed and now it works again! Why the on-again, off-again issues? (Banging my head here!)

Comment: Well, your question is kind of confusing. Often while I was learning I tried (as you have probably done) change lots of stuff to achieve what I wanted. And often when getting rid of a property and adding other you mess your code a bit because it "could" have been possible that getting rid of one but NOT adding another would have been the answer. While working I recomend to you to test (while you are learning) in your browser every single property you change before starting with the next, And also, never forget to use `control+f5` when refreshing your localhost web window.

Comment: If you just use f5, so very often browser's cache will mess with your code because, basically, you have changde css properties, you use f5, you see no change and you think it didn't work. while browser just didn't even refresh the new code. Finally chrome inspector (for me) it's a GREAT tool to get use. you see mistakes, can add any property to see if it works, edit yor html... basically when you get use you so often change your code in the inspector and later you translate it to your real pages.

Comment: Finally while I use just chrome except when testing my webs for browser compatibility, You may find the same tools wih firefox, explorer and others. I think lately firefox have improved a lot so I'm even willing to give it a try ( I doubt explorer will ever have anything worth... and even if they does I woudn't like to lose any bit of my hate for this browser)

Comment: Btw if this answer was the right one for you, an "acepted answer" check is always welcome

Comment: Thanks very much Alvaro! :-) I do use Firefox and I use firebug to inspect my code - and often I can find problems that way. You are right - I know I should delete only one line at a time (or add 1 line at a time) in my css. I can't say how many times I have remmed everything out and then tested it by un-remming my css line by line until I find the mistake. My bad, I just got impatient and deleted it all at once. However, now that I tested it in each browser it does seem to work now - thank you so much!

Comment: It was weird also because I found an extra } in my .css and when I removed just the } the image also disappeared. However, as I said above - it now works correctly - ALL of it, in ALL browsers (expect of course old versions of IE!) Thanks so much! I can say goodbye to old-fashioned center tags! :-D

Comment: Glad I could help. I wish you good luck on your future projects